# Redirect to an external website on to particular section (No anchor tag)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

There is a business directory website that lists my name and business along with others.

I want to create a link on my website, where users on clicking it, go to the directory website and to the page section where it mentions me name and business.

There is way like `<a href="http://website.com/some-page#id>Link</a>`

But directory website has no unique identifiers. Its arranged in a tabular fashion(not html table).

I want to know if there is any jquery/javascript solution for this.

Thanks :)

Comment: How would you get your jQuery/JavaScript code onto the other website? No, you can't do this.

Comment: This has nothing to do with JS and everything to do with the structure of the website you want to link to. If, as you seem to suggest, their content is framed or AJAX-loaded, you don't have an identifier to link into. JS won't solve that.

Comment: @ceejayoz you're right.

Comment: @Utkanos Are there any other alternatives?

Comment: Not really. If the target website doesn't make content easily linkable, there's not a lot you can do.